# Replacing layer weights with torch.sparse tensors

Tags: pytorch, sparse-matrix, tensor

Let's say I have a layer defined `C = nn.Conv2d(1,3,3, bias=False)`, ie, 1 input channel, 3 output channels and a kernel size of 3x3. The internal weight of this layer is thus a tensor of shape `(3,1,3,3)`; I can access this with C.weight.data. Now suppose that this internal weight is very sparse; it's full of zeros and has only a few nonzero values. I can easily construct a sparse tensor from the weight by:

```
idx = C.weight.data.nonzero().T
values = C.weight.data[C.weight.data!=0]
sp_T = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(idx, values, C.weight.data.size())
```

Is it possible to store the conv layer's weights as this sparse tensor somehow? I tried simply doing `C.weight.data = sp_T` but it throws an error. It would be pretty convenient if we could store all the weights in a model in this sparsified way.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62355485/688080

Comment: It does help, the assignment works fine this way. Unfortunately the forward pass fails as `NotImplementedError: Could not run 'aten::thnn_conv2d_forward' with arguments from the 'SparseCPU' backend.` (with torch 1.10.0+cpu). But this is quite useful; I believe I could just store sparse weights, then have my own custom conv layer where I call `to_dense()` before running `F.conv2d` or something.