# Convert weight and bias to sparse tensor pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensor

I'm trying to convert `torch.nn.Parameters` to sparse tensor. Pytorch documents say that Parameters is a [Tensor's](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor) subclass. Tensor support `to_sparse` method but if I convert a `Parameters` to sparse, it will give me:
`TypeError: cannot assign 'torch.cuda.sparse.FloatTensor' as parameter 'weight' (torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)`
**Is there a way to bypass this and use sparse tensor for Parameters?**
Here is example code to produce the problem:

```
for name, module in net.named_modules():
    if isinstance(module, torch.nn.Conv2d):
        module.weight = module.weight.data.to_sparse()
        module.bias = module.bias.data.to_sparse()
```

Comment: ```module.weight.data = module.weight.data.to_sparse()```  or ```from torch.nn.parameter import Parameter   \n   module.weight = Parameter(module.weight.data.to_sparse())```

Comment: Hi, please answer so I can mark it

Comment: Haha, it’s okay, just solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[torch.Tensor.to_sparse()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=to_sparse#torch.Tensor.to_sparse) returns a sparse copy of the tensor which cannot be assigned to `module.weight` since this is an instance of `torch.nn.Parameter`. So, you should rather do:

```
module.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(module.weight.data.to_sparse())
module.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(module.bias.data.to_sparse())
```

Please note that `Parameters` are a specific type of Tensor that is marked as being a parameter from an `nn.Module`, so they are different from ordinary Tensors.